# Are Meteor apps indexable by search engines?

Tags: javascript, search-engine, meteor

As far as I know, Google will index a page if it meets at least one of two conditions:

1. The page loaded with javascript off has content.
2. If the page requires javascript it is located at a url under a hashbang. Like this: `http://www.example.com/#!/page-name`

If I have that right, then [meteor](http://meteor.com) apps (like meteor.com, which lacks content when javascript is off) won't be indexed by Google.

Did I miss something? Is there some other mechanism in play or planned to make meteor apps indexable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Simple indexing is now included in the spiderable package, more features are planned for an upcoming release.

Recently added to the [meteor](http://meteor.com) FAQ:

> ### Can Meteor serve static HTML? Can Meteor sites be indexed by Google?
>
> Yes. Add the "spiderable" smart package to include support for emitting static HTML to search engines, complete with valid links. The spiderable package implements Google's AJAX Crawling Specification. See the [spiderable documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable) for details.
>
> This version of spiderable is specifically for search engines. A future version of Meteor will also send HTML to web browsers on initial page load. The Meteor templating system was designed specifically to support this use case.

Answer (score 7):

I made a smartpackage to get some basics for crawling ready. 
https://github.com/lvbreda/meteor_seo_smartpackage
Check it out, fork it, whatever you want .

Answer (score 3):

No, they aren't because they give back an empty page and they don't execute the sockjs stuff. The devs plan to work on server side rendering which gives a page with inital data to start of with such that search engines can store such data. It's a bit trickier than the AJAX that Google processes...

Comment: Actually, now they do

Answer (score -3):

Checkout DerbyJS and Yahoo Mojito. Both frameworks are SEO friendly.

[SEO and latency issues with Javascript frameworks](http://www.phamcom.com/2012/07/ultimate-javascript-framework.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have seen both. I was specifically looking for information about meteor.